# Can I put shared applescript code in a separate file and load it in various scripts?

Tags: applescript

I'm starting to poke around with Applescript and am looking at writing a few scripts for managing windows.  A common task they will all need is to get the current screen size.

I've created a screen_size subroutine that seems to work, and I want to be able to share that with all my scripts.  However, I can't figure out a way to put that in a separate file that I can load in my other scripts.  I tried creating a separate screen_size.scpt file and use `load script "screen_size.scpt"`, but I get an error about "can't make "screen_size.scpt" into a type file".

There has to be a way to do this, but I haven't been able to find anything online about how to do it.

EDIT:

The POSIX stuff suggested isn't working for me.  I'm able to create the file object, but it refuses to convert to an alias, saying it can't find the file (looks like the POSIX file stays relative instead of expanding fully).

I found a suggestion online to use Finder, and have gotten the following working to get an alias:

```
tell application "Finder"
  set _myPath to container of (path to me) as text
end tell

set _loadPath to (_myPath & "screen_size.scpt")
set _loadAlias to alias _loadPath
```

However, the next line fails with a syntax error, claiming that _loadAlias isn't a variable:

```
property _ScreenSize : load script _loadAlias
```

Every variation of this I've tried (doing the alias in the load call, etc) fails, always claiming the variable doesn't exist, even though I know it's being set and working as I can display it.  What's going on?  Why is it claiming a variable doesn't exist when it obviously does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppleScript is doing some really weird things when saving and I haven't figured out what's going on, but I ended up getting something to work.

Here's what I have:

```
on load_script(_scriptName)
  tell application "Finder"
    set _myPath to container of (path to me) as text
  end tell

  set _loadPath to (_myPath & _scriptName)
  load script (alias _loadPath)
end load_script

set _ScreenSize to load_script("screen_size.scpt")

set _bounds to _ScreenSize's screen_size()
-- ...
```

The other answers were saying to set _ScreenSize as a property, but that would cause a syntax error which prevented me from ever saving the file.  When I did it just using `set` it worked.

I wasn't ever able to get the POSIX path stuff suggested to work, but poking Finder for the path worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

In order to execute an action from another script, you'll have to create an handler in the script you're going to load (in your answer you already did this with "screen_size()".

In your case this script will be "screen_size.scpt".
So "screen_size.scpt" will have to look something like this:

```
on screen_size()
       --your actions
return [yourvalue] --the value you want to pass to the other script
end screen_size()
```

The script you'll load it from will have to look like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set _myPath to (container of (path to me) as text & "screen_size.scpt") as alias
end tell
set _ScreenSizeScript to load script _myPath

set _bounds to _ScreenSizeScript's screen_size()
```

If it doesn't work, or you don't understand me completely, feel free to ask (:

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to do this. Load the file into a property and access it that way

```
property _ScreenSize : load script (alias "pathtoscript")

_ScreenSize's doStuff()
```

and for relative paths try this:

```
set p to "./screen_size.scpt" 
set a to POSIX file p
```

so perhaps this will work:

```
set p to "./screen_size.scpt" 
set a to POSIX file p 

property _ScreenSize : load script (alias a)

_ScreenSize's doStuff()
```

Comment: can "pathtoscript" be relative (so, just the name of the script since it's in the same directory)?

Comment: I tried it using just the file name and get a syntax error: `File alias screen_size.scpt of <<script>> wasn't found.`  The code I have is `property _ScreenSize : load script (alias "screen_size.scpt")`

Comment: Don't know much about applescript but I think the best way is to use POSIX paths if you want relative paths.

Comment: You need the full path load script (alias "hd:lib:screen_size.scpt")

Comment: or (path to me):screen_size.scpt

I have no mac at work so I cannot check that it works.

Comment: Trying to keep it generic (might throw these up on github so other people could use them), so I don't want to use absolute paths at all.  I'll try the path to me thing.

Comment: try this:
set p to "./screen_size.scpt" 
set a to POSIX file p 
then a should resolve to something like hd:your folder:screen_size.scpt
then a should re

Comment: no good.  I can't use the resulting file in the load (claims the variable isn't defined), and I can't convert it to an alias either.

Answer (score 1):

I have people using my libraries on a daily basis, so I first ensure the library is here before calling it.
Let's say I have a library "Lib.Excel.app" (save as non-editable application with Satimage's Smile).
At the beginning of a script that makes use of it, I "load" the library by using this code :

```
set commonCodeFile to (path to library folder as string) & "Scripts:CommonLibraries:Lib.Excel.app"

tell application "Finder"
    if not (exists (file commonCodeFile)) then error ("\"Lib.Excel\"
" & "
should be found in folder
" & "
scroll > CommonLibraries")
end tell

global cc -- make it short and easy to write :)
set cc to load script alias ccFile
```

Then when I have to use a function from the lib, I just call it like this :

```
set {what, a} to cc's veryNiceFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need the full path to the script however.

I believe you can still use "path to me" to get the path to the app executing the current script, and you can then modify that path to point to your sub-folder containing the scripts.

I used this technique to get around AppleScripts (former) 32k text size limits years ago for some really large/complex IRC scripting.

I think I still have all those old scripts in my G4, which is under the desk in my office at work. Sadly it's behind a Enet switch and I can't VNC into it otherwise I'd have tons of sample code to post.

Comment: how would I use "path to me" to do it?  "path to me" gives me the full path to the script that's running *including the script filename*.  I need to remove the file name from that and add the name of the script I want to include, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN load the script in a variable, but you have to declare it first.

```
property _ScreenSize : missing value

tell application "Finder" to set _myPath to container of (path to me) as text

set _loadPath to (_myPath & "screen_size.scpt")

set _loadAlias to alias _loadPath

set _ScreenSize to (load script _loadAlias)
```